# How save file in utf-8 when saving html-page using casperjs?

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I have the code which save page in ANSI:

```
casper.thenOpen(myurli, function(){

   var page1 = this.getHTML();
   fs.write(file_path, page1, 'wb');

});
```

How save file in utf-8 when saving html-page using casperjs?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following statement:

```
fs.write(file_path, page1, {
    mode: 'w',
    charset: 'UTF-8'
});
```